# Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot - pastebin ref included

Tags: boot

- For an unknown reason my Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot - it was fine yesterday but won't boot this morning.
- Booted in with a live-thumb-drive (also Ubuntu 20.04), tried boot-repair and did all it asked but this did not solve the problem. Tried this several times but no luck.  Here is the ref to the latest report:
  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XBXztrRXkG/
- During the process of trying to fix matters I used GParted and now can't re-mount the two partitions - I presume this will be reflected in the report (mentioned above).
- My pc is a Lenovo with 16 MB RAM and 2TB HDD
- "error 1962: No operating system found" is shown when I try to boot. I have ensured that the BIOS boot sequence is OK.

Thank you very much indeed for your help.
Sincerely
DB

Comment: *"During the process of trying to fix matters I used GParted "* What did you do with gparted? Boot repair is not meant to manage partitions.

Comment: With GParted I tried editing the "UEFI" boot partition - but it did not help. I really would appreciate some help on where I go from here. I should mention that my pc was originally Windows but I replaced it with Ubuntu some years ago "erasing" the Windows part.  However, I believe that when one does this the Windows boot system (UEFI) is kept - - perhaps this might help in the solution of the problem?